# How to perform an insert into select

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to perform an insert into select with mysql.
Is it possible to insert data like this ? or is there an other way to do that ?

A = 17

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (x1, x2, x3) 
  SELECT (Y,Z) FROM TABLE2 
  WHERE CONDITION, A
```

Thanks,

Comment: 3 columns, 2 values. why wouldn't that work.....

Comment: The table1 3 column (x1,x2,x3), the data insert (Y,Z) from Table2 and A=7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get it from select statment

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (x1, x2, x3) 
  SELECT (Y,Z,17) FROM TABLE2 
  WHERE CONDITION;
```

Comment: @Gaetan Please check this

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your query, it looks like you want to insert `A` in column `x3`. Your query should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (x1, x2, x3) 
  SELECT Y,Z,A FROM TABLE2 
  WHERE CONDITION
```

Or you can instantly insert the value of `A` directly, assuming that it's an integer.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (x1, x2, x3) 
  SELECT Y,Z,17 FROM TABLE2 
  WHERE CONDITION
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) a little bit more if it doesn't make sense.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (x1, x2, x3) 
  SELECT Y,Z,A FROM TABLE2 
  WHERE A = 17
```

Sometimes you also want to insert hardcoded details (i.e. `17`) else there may be Unique constraint fail etc. So use following in such situation where you override some values of the columns.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (x1, x2, x3) 
  SELECT Y,Z,17 FROM TABLE2
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (x1, x2, x3) 
  SELECT Y,Z,17 FROM TABLE2 
  WHERE CONDITION
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (x1, x2, x3) 
  SELECT (X,Y,Z) FROM TABLE2 
  WHERE A = 17
```